# Rails Server Memory Leak/Bloating Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory-leaks

We are running 2 rails application on server with 4GB of ram. Both servers use rails 3.2.1 and when run in either development or production mode, the servers eat away ram at incredible speed consuming up-to 1.07GB ram each day. Keeping the server running for just 4 days triggered all memory alarms in monitoring and we had just 98MB ram free.

We tried active-record optimization related to bloating but still no effect. Please help us figure out how can we trace the issue that which of the controller is at fault.

Using mysql database and webrick server.
Thanks!

Comment: You are using Webrick in production?

Comment: you can try using relic rpm tools to check wats going on.

Comment: stab in the dark: psych (yaml parser) leaks memory in 1.9.2 - check YAML::ENGINE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is incredibly hard to answer, without looking into the project details itself. Though I am quite sure you won't be using Webrick in your target production build(right?), so check if it behaves the same under Passenger or whatever is your choice.

Also without knowing the details of the project I would suggest looking at features like generating pdfs, csv parsing, etc. Seen a case, where generating pdf files have been eating resources in a similar fashion, leaving like 5mb of not garbage collected memory for each run.

Good luck.

Comment: If using Passenger there is a [PassengerMaxRequests](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerMaxRequests) option you can use to reboot server instances after a certain number of requests. Though it clearly states you should sort out memory leak issues in your app.